# While trying to access NSBitmapImageRep getting "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have code:
*setUpMainImage.h:*

```
#import "MainOpenGLView.h"

@interface MainOpenGLView (setUpMainImage)
- (void)loadImage;
@end
```

*setUpMainImage.m:*

```
#import "setUpMainImage.h"

@implementation MainOpenGLView (setUpMainImage)
- (void)loadImage {
    CIImage *_tempImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapImageRep:_bottomTextureBitmap];
    CIFilter *_tempFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
    [_tempFilter setDefaults];
    [_tempFilter setValue:_tempImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [_tempFilter setValue:0 forKey:@"inputSaturation"];
    _tempImage = [_tempFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    _topTextureBitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:_tempImage];
}
- (void)topTextureImage {
    float _topWide = _topTextureBitmap.pixelsWide;
    float _topHigh = _topTextureBitmap.pixelsHigh;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _top_image_texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _topWide, _topHigh, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [_topTextureBitmap bitmapData]);

    NSLog(@"_topWide:%f, _topHigh:%f", _topWide, _topHigh);
}
@end
```

and

*MainOpenGLView.h:*

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>

@interface MainOpenGLView : NSOpenGLView {
    NSBitmapImageRep *_topTextureBitmap;
    NSBitmapImageRep *_bottomTextureBitmap;
    GLuint _top_image_texture;
}
@end
```

*MainOpenGLView.m:*

```
#import "MainOpenGLView.h"
#import "setUpMainImage.h"

@implementation MainOpenGLView
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
        self = [super initWithCoder: coder];
        [self loadImage];
        [self topTextureImage];
        return self;
    }
@end
```

And I get error
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x10)`

at `setUpMainImage.m` in line:

`float _topWide = _topTextureBitmap.pixelsWide;`

I'm using ARC(Automatic Reference Counting), so I am not retaining/releasing any objects manually. Maby ARC releases `_topTextureBitmap` too early?